# Setting line spacing in Eledmac sidenotes

Tags: line-spacing, eledmac, sidenotes

In Eledmac (or Reledmac), is it possible to set the line spacing of sidenotes by inserting a command in the preamble? My project is doublespaced in the main text, but I would like the sidenotes to be singlespaced.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: for now, not, as I know. But you could open an issue on the github page.